# Pass a message to activity to close itself

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I have a PhoneStateListener which listens to incoming call and Call idle states. On incoming call, I start off an activity to overlay my screen over the default InCallScreen and upon pressing End Call, I close the activity.

But there's an issue when the caller himself ends the call before we pick it up (missed call for us), in which case, my activity doesn't know that it should then close itself.

What mechanism should I use, to pass this message to the activity, so that it knows when to close itself.

Pls guide.
Omkar Ghaisas

Answer (score 1):

I think adding `finish();` to the `PhoneStateListener` should end the `Activity` for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Telephony API](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect18_d1e18123.html) might be of some use. You could use it to monitor if a call is in progress, and once the call ends, call finish() on your activity.

Comment: Calling finish from within the activity to close itself is understandable, but how do I have the broadcast receiver or phone state listener class to invoke a finish() on the activity which is active on screen. I guess, I would need to implement a BroadcastReceiver within the activity itself and then listen for a particular state and then upon reaching a given call state, call finish(); ?